# unable to fetch values from JSONArray object ,I just forEach , ItemFileReadStore, JSON.parse

Tags: javascript, json

HI,

I am fetching values from database and putting values in JSONObject 
like

```
 [{"JAN":"17"},{"FEB":"19"},{"MAR":"21"},{"APR":"23"},{"MAY":"24"},{"JUN":"27"}]
```

After that putting JSONObject in JSONArray and sending back the responce to jsp page.

In JSP :

```
dojo.xhrGet( {
        url : "/POC/Action.do",
            handleAs : "json",
            sync: true,
            load : function(response, ioArgs) {
                alert("retrived response ------"+response);
                     //Here i need to fetch only the values like {17,19,21,23,24,27} not the key from response.. but  i am unable to fetch it 

                return response;
            },
              error: function(response, ioArgs){
              dojo.byId("grid").innerHTML = "An error occurred, with response: " + response;              return response;
            },
            handleAs: "json"
        });
```

need to fetch only the values like {17,19,21,23,24,27} not the key from response.. but  i am unable to fetch it. I just forEach , ItemFileReadStore, JSON.parse but unable .. please help

Answer (score 0):

If your response from web server (you can check using fiddler etc) the below data:

```
[{"JAN":"17"},{"FEB":"19"},{"MAR":"21"},{"APR":"23"},{"MAY":"24"},{"JUN":"27"}]
```

Then you can do below in response handler:

```
var output = [];
for(var i in response)
  for(var x in response[i])
     output.push(response[i][x]);
```

The output array will have all the values that you need